# Are unfalsifiable statements valid? Two Medical Doctors met with Jesus and wrote a statement about it

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, popper, falsifiability

I'm interested in your take on unfalsifiable statements. Please consider the following scenario:

Let’s say two medical doctors living together, Bill & Janet, claims that they met “Jesus” in their house yesterday.

They’re both GP:s with 20 years of experience.

When they met with Jesus they wrote a statement, signed by them both as medical doctors(to use their authority to confirm the hypothesis that Jesus exists and is alive), saying the following:

1. Jesus was alive and awake, lying on their sofa.
2. He spoke to them about the bible and taught them the following two quotes:
   “The LORD is my light and my salvation; whom shall I fear? The LORD is the stronghold of my life; of whom shall I be afraid?” Psalm 27:1
   “Greater love has no one than this: to lay down one's life for one's friends”.  - John 15:13

Bill & Janet have claimed that they have never ever seen a bible before and because they remember these quotes it means that they’ve got to have learned it from Jesus being inside their house.

3. They checked Jesus and both of them testifies that he was in excellent health condition.
4. Jesus left the house after teaching them the quotes from the bible and would never be seen again.
5. Janet & Bill Claims that they never lie.
6. Conclusion: Jesus does exist and the statement, written by two experienced M.Ds, will be proof of this. If needed both Janet & Bill are willing to testify under oath in court to anyone who challenges their claim.

Both Janet & Bill believes no one can falsify their claim since only they were present to witness Jesus speaking to them, there is no way any outside person can falsify this because they would have to had been inside the house to gather proof that Jesus was not there at the moment they claim to have met with him.

The written statement is then copied and put into your mailbox. Your spouse reads the statement and becomes at first convinced about Jesus existing because of this statement but then she turns to you to ask what your thoughts as a philosopher are about accepting this unfalsifiable statement, since it can´t be falsified do we have to accept it as being true?

Anyone who challenges Bill & Janet will be met with the argument: **We would not have written the statement if it would not have happened and since you were not inside our house at that precise moment you can never prove us being wrong.**

Comment: Questions asking for users' take on some issue are off-topic on this site. Most claims do not get to be proven wrong, they are simply dismissed. One does not even need to think of the claimants as lying, just mistaken is enough, until proven otherwise. For a claim to be entitled to a consideration there has to be sufficient preliminary evidence to warrant it, see [burden of proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burden_of_proof_(philosophy)). And extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence, which a signed letter is not.

Comment: I have an invisible, immaterial pink dragon in my garage. Can you prove it's not the case ? No ? Then it must be true. Even if Janet and Bill are sincere, they could be mistaken. Maybe they just met my friend Bob, who has long hair, knows a few bible quotes and like to prank people that way. Considering the lack of evidence, not believing them is the rational thing to do, and it is in no way equivalent to calling them liars.

Comment: @Conifold: Thanks, I agree with the BoP theory.

Comment: @armand: Thanks, Great example.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom Many thanks! I was wondering if their testimony and handwritten statements ever will be enough as evidence for the claim? They can always adapt their story to new conditions we ask them about.

Comment: Do they speak koin Greek, or Hebrew? If not he must have been speaking in tongues, a religious concept for which there is no evidence. All we know about the appearance of Jesus, is that it was made-up long after the prohibition on graven images had faded. How did they know it was Jesus, and what did he look like inc clothing? Alien abduction-claimers almost invariably reference imagery in recent films. Where were the stigmata that they must have observed doing the health check? Most films get this wrong. Like the Cottingley Fairies, many many things would have to different, were this case true

Answer (score 3):

People always seem to conflate the experience of something with a theory about something...

1. Assuming that Bill & Janet are not lying, they clearly had an *experience* of seeing someone sitting on their sofa reciting bible quotes
2. Assuming that Bill & Janet are not lying, they clearly have a *theory* that this experience involved Jesus Christ showing up for a lazy sit-down

The experience is a singleton: it happened once, at a defined point in space and time, and will never recur. The theory is what they're trying to prove to others by using logic and a signed affidavit, and it is up to others to decide whether they believe it.

In the scientific context, we demand replicable singletons: singleton events that can be reproduced (more or less) in different space-time points. When we see enough replicable singletons we can make an **inference** to a theory about what causes the replicable singletons to occur. With seemingly one-time events the process of inference becomes much trickier. It's not impossible to infer something from a one-time event, but it usually means drawing on analogies, historical or mythological stories, or other not-quite-on-point information to flesh out the body of the theory.

In short, I have no reason to doubt that Bill & Janet had an experience of some sort (even if it was only a hallucination or mystical vision); that's perfectly valid. I do have reason to doubt the theory that they have spun from this singleton experience.

Answer (score 1):

There are many recorded cases where the logic of this example applies. One famous case, which became known as "the ladies of the Trianon" involved two ladies who claimed to have somehow visited the gardens of the Trianon, Versailles in the time of Marie Anotinette. In 1911 they published their account as *An Adventure* under the pseudonyms of Elizabeth Morison and Frances Lamont.

Opinions were divided. Some accepted the authors' claims, many laughed the whole thing off as a prank.

Decades later, their identities were revealed as respected Oxford academics  Anne Moberly and Eleanor Jourdain. However the climate of the day had moved further away from psychic phenomena towards a materialistic atheism. These two pressures - academic credentials and materialist scepticism - kind of cancelled out. The majority still saw it as a prank, but a fair community accepted the word of the respected academics.

Later still, after one of them had died, the other confessed that it had indeed been a prank all along. But there remains a hard core who believe that this was just a white lie to make her life more tolerable.

The moral of all this is, that if you encounter claims which go beyond scientific knowledge then they are neither verifiable nor falsifiable via reasoned argument. They might be true, they might not. If none of them were ever true, then science could not advance. All one can do is make a subjective assessment of the likelihood either way, and apply for a research grant. But in the case of your Jesus example, few worthwhile institutions would offer one.

Answer (score 0):

> since it can´t be falsified do we have to accept it as being true?

No. Just because we can't for sure say it's false doesn't mean it's true. The truth value is simply unknown.

Btw. Everything about this story could have happened exactly how they claimed, with the only difference being that the person wasn't actually Jesus. The only special claim made is that that person **was Jesus** (as opposed to **said he was Jesus**, or no claim at all regarding identity). If we take away that claim, the story is still as unfalsifiable as before, but we are more inclined to believe it because the impact of this story being true (or false) is most likely non-existent (except for the case where this is an alibi for something else :-P  ).